# Passing an array by reference using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

In some new territory working with pointers and references, I am attempting to pass an array by reference into a function using a pointer, however I keep getting errors no matter what I try, I am sure the problem is very simple to fix but I just cant seem to wrap my head around it, can anyone see the mistake im making? any help will go a long way thanks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>   
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

//Inline function 
inline double getFahrenheit(double theCelsius)
{ 
//Convert the celcius to farenheit   
return (theCelsius + 32) * 5 / 9;  
}

void outputWeather(double *temperaturesArray, const string WEEK_DAY_NAMES[], const     double MAX_NUMBER)
{
     //this is a counter that will increment through the days and various 
     int counter;
     //reset the counter to 0 so we can use it again       
     counter = 0;
     //print a header       
     cout << "THIS WEEKS TEMPERATURE REPORT " << endl;
     //print a divider 
     cout << "=============================" << endl;
     //while the counter is less than 7 repeat again
     while(counter < MAX_NUMBER)
     {
         //print out the temperatures by day          
         cout << WEEK_DAY_NAMES[counter] << "     " << temperaturesArray[counter] << "\370C    " << getFahrenheit(temperaturesArray[counter]) <<"\370F    "<< endl;
         //increase the counter by 1
         counter +=1;  
     }
}

//Function that will determine whether or not the value the user entered was numeric     and within the range
double checkValidation(string weekDay)
{
 //Create a variable to store a valid number
 double validNumber;

 //This will hold the value for the lowest  
 const double MIN_NUMBER = 1;
 //This will hold the value for the highest temperature
 const double MAX_NUMBER = 365;
 //This will hold the value for the valid number that the user will eventually enter 
 validNumber = 0.0;

 //This will alert the user to enter a temperature for that day of the week
 cout << "Please enter the temperature for " << weekDay << endl;
 //This will take in teh value the user entered for teh temperature 
 cin >> validNumber; 

     //If the text the user entered was not numeric start again             
 if(cin.fail())            
 {
     //C++ built in methods for clearing the cin                     
     cin.clear();              
     fflush(stdin);

     //alert the user what they typed was wrong 
     cout << "invalid input. please try again and enter a numeric value" << endl; 
     //pass in the weekeday and start over
     checkValidation(weekDay);                     
 } 
 else 
 {
     //if teh number falls outside the range
     if(validNumber < MIN_NUMBER || validNumber > MAX_NUMBER)
     {
         //Alert the user that it was outside the range           
         cout << "invalid input. please try again and enter a value between -90 and 60" << endl; 
         //pass in the weekday and try again          
         checkValidation(weekDay);
     }

 }
 //return the valid number    
 return validNumber;  

}


int main()
{
    //this is a counter that will increment through the days and various 
    int counter;
    //a constant to hold the variable for the number of days
    const int MAX_COUNTER = 7;
    //an array that will hold all the days of the week
    const string WEEK_DAY_NAMES[] = 
    { 
          "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" 
    };

    //this will hold all of teh temperatures
    double temperaturesArray[MAX_COUNTER]; 
    //start the counter off at 0      
    counter = 0; 

    //begin telling the user to enter temperatures by printing a header
    cout << "Please enter the temperature for every day of the week " << endl;
    //while the counter is less than 7 we will repeat
    while(counter < MAX_COUNTER)
    {                                                       
    //add temperature to the array 
    temperaturesArray[counter] = checkValidation(WEEK_DAY_NAMES[counter]); 
    //add 1 to the counter            
    counter +=1;                     

    }

    double * arrayPointer = new double[MAX_COUNTER];

    arrayPointer = &temperaturesArray;

    outputWeather(arrayPointer, WEEK_DAY_NAMES, MAX_COUNTER);       

system("PAUSE");
return 0;              
}
```

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: @imulsion the current code is telling me - cannot convert `double (*)[7]' to `double*' in assignment

Comment: You can never pass anything by reference "by passing a pointer". You pass things by reference by passing a *reference*. If you pass a pointer, then you're passing them by pointer.

Comment: Are you getting compilation error? I can see a mistake in following line:
double * arrayPointer = new double[MAX_COUNTER];
arrayPointer = &temperaturesArray;

Comment: @ritesh_nitw That is where I keep getting most of the errors, what is correct way to write this line?

Comment: Most of the comments in your code are bad because they don’t provide information – they merely paraphrase your code. Such comments don’t provide any value and should be removed. Use comments to provide information that is *not* contained in code.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, the size of an array is encoded into its type.

There is no general "array of doubles" type. But there is an "array of 7 doubles" type, and an "array of 13 doubles" type, and so on.

So to pass an array *as an array*, and not simply as a pointer, to a function, you need to encode the precise type in the function's signature.

It won't be "a function which takes an array", but "a function which takes an array of size 7".

The way to do that is as follows:

```
void f(double (&arr)[7]);
```

Or of course, you can template it, if the array size is not fixed:

```
template <size_t N>
void f(double (&arr)[N]);
```

But really, what you're trying to do shouldn't be done using raw arrays at all.

Use the standard library vector.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, replacing line

```
arrayPointer = &temperaturesArray;
```

with

```
arrayPointer = temperaturesArray;
```

makes the code to compile.

Notice that `arrayPointer` is of type `double*` and `temperaturesArray` is of type `double[MAX_COUNTER]` (with `MAX_COUNTER = 7`). Hence, you can assign `arrayPointer` to the address of a `double` but you cannot assign `arrayPointer` to the address of a `double[MAX_COUNTER]`. That's what the original code attempted to do and thus, it failed to compile.

On the other hand, each element of a `double[MAX_COUNTER]` is a `double`. In particular, the first element is a `double` and you can assign its address to `arrayPointer`:

```
arrayPointer = &temperaturesArray[0];
```

The fix above is just a synctatic sugar for this line. Indeed, when you assign an object of type "*array of type T*" (e.g. `double[MAX_COUNTER]`) to a "*pointer of type T*", then the compiler performs the so called *array-to-pointer conversion* which means that is assigns the address of the first array element to the pointer.

Now a little remark on your code (with the provided fix), specifically, the following lines:

```
double * arrayPointer = new double[MAX_COUNTER];
arrayPointer = temperaturesArray;
```

The first line above allocates heap memory to store an array of `MAX_COUNTER` objects of type `double`. Then the address of the first element of this array is assigned to `arrayPointer`.

Then, the following line reassigns `arrayPointer` to the address of the first element of `temperaturesArray`. Therefore, the address of the first element of the heap allocated array is lost and you can no longer `delete` it. Remeber that every call to `new` must be matched by a call to `delete` (otherwise you have a memory leak). In this particular case, however, the best thing to do isn't call `delete`. Actually, you should eliminate the call to `new` since the heap memory is never used. More precisely, you can remove the first line above.